# ASP.NET Accordion height messed up when starting in collapsed mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, height, accordion, autosize

I have an ASP.NET accordion rendered by this markup (removed some CssClass properties):

```
<toolkit:Accordion runat="server" AutoSize="Fill" 
    RequireOpenedPane="false" SelectedIndex="0" Height="400">...
```

This renders OK in terms of height. Now when I change one setting `SelectedIndex="-1"` to have everything collapsed at load time, the height is messed up when you start opening panes. The **visible height** remains 400px but the content of the panes is clipped at the bottom even though there is a scrollbar (see screenshot http://awesomescreenshot.com/00e6jj00f). I'm guessing the height of the headers is not subtracted from the pane height in this case. Also when I changed the height property to 300, the same behavior happens with visible height 300. In the css file I only change colors, borders and some padding. No heights or overflow set there.

I tested IE6, IE9 (several modes), Firefox 3, Chrome 8 and Safari 5 (Win).

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this or what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by downloading the source code for the toolkit, fixing the JavaScript in there that calculates the height... recompile amuse the new dll.